# Can KDE Legacy Applications (X11) scaling be applied per-app basis?

Tags: x11, kde

If I have X11 app A1 and A2, can I make A1 be scaled by the system and A2 scale itself? Or is the setting applied to all X11 apps without exceptions?

[image]